# Chrome extension: how to send message to default_popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I'm writing an extension that has commands and a default_popup page. Commands or context menu items are initiated (caught) by the background page, which then sends a message to the active tab to interact with it. This works fine.

But when the active page is the default_popup, how to send messages to it?

Default_popup is not a tab or a frame; it only has a url which is: `chrome-extension://<extension_id>/<filename>`.

It's not injected with the content script even with `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` in the manifest. If one includes the content script by way of a `<script>` tag it runs it: it's able to send messages to the background script for example.

But I need to communicate **from** the background script **to** the popup, not the other way around. (The background script needs to initiate communication, not just respond).

Is this possible?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown so it can't receive messages when it's hidden. Hence, usually it only makes sense to send messages **from** the popup, but if you insist simply use chrome.runtime.sendMessage as it'll be received by all chrome-extension:// scripts of the extension that are currently open. So if you have two windows and each has a popup open, both will receives the message. They'll have to check chrome.windows API to see whose window is active.

Comment: You are right. What I ended up doing was open a port for long-term communication, where the background page and all pages exchange messages. The messages sent by the background page are received by all pages (that have the extension loaded), including the popup when it is open (and if it was injected the content script by way of a script tag). Then each page tests if it's the active page with document.focus() and does smth if it is, and nothing it it isn't. -- Is it better to use chrome.windows or document.focus?

Comment: chrome.windows.getCurrent doesn't seem to see the popup at all; the solution where the page itself decides whether it should act upon the message, appears to work fine so far.

Comment: getCurrent won't work in the popup because the popup itself is a separate window. Use getLastFocused.